# Mavericks startup script

Tags: linux, macos, mac, script, plist

I am trying to write a small script to launch when user logs on. I have searched and got the script to work but unable to run at log on with .plist

We have active directory setup.
When the user logs in using their credentials the script manually works once executed

```
tell application "finder"
    set MyName to do shell script "whoami"
    mount volume "smb://server/folder/" & MyName
end tell
```

or

```
set MyName to do shell script "whoami"
mount volume "smb://server/folder/" & MyName
```

and saved it as .scpt  both manually works

Or i need to use it this way

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set MyName to do shell script "whoami"
    mount volume "smb://server/folder/" & MyName
end tell
```

save it as .sh

Now the plist is saved in `/Library/LaunchAgents`:

```
<plist version="1.0">

<dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.script</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
       <string>/Users/Shared/SCRIPT.sh</string>
    </array>
</dict>

</plist>
```

and do the following command

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.script.plist
```

It does not work. Cant get the drive to auto-mount during logon

Please help. I am not a programmer so please be specific.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: Hey, I cleaned up some of your script formatting for this site. It seemed like some characters were cut off, so I tried to replace them to create a valid PLIST, but double-check that it accurately reflects what was actually in the file. Also, are you using Linux or OSX? They're two different operating systems as far as this is concerned, and will have different answers (but you tagged for both).

Comment: I'm using osx 10.9 mavericks....in the post i removed the > because it wouldn't show all the codes...thank you...looks much better

Answer (score 0):

Your script is an applescript, not a shell script, so you can't execute it directly. I think it'd work to have the `ossascript` command interpret it:

```
<array>
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
    <string>/Users/Shared/SCRIPT.sh</string>
</array>
```

(& please use a more appropriate file extension than ".sh")

BTW, I'm pretty sure you want `KeepAlive` set to `<false/>` -- with it set to `<true/>`, your script will be rerun continuously rather than just once.